# JQuery Functionality that allows users to dynamically resize content windows

Tags: jquery, html

Is there any jQuery plugin or functionality that would allow for a user to click and drag windows so that they would resize?

For an example of what I'm trying to accomplish, I want to have the window resize capabilities  just like Xcode does, where when you drag one window and the other one resizes too.

EDIT: When I say windows, I mean divs, not the browser window.

Comment: What do you mean by 'windows'? Divs inside a page?

Comment: You mean the browser window, or just some divs?

Comment: Just some divs, not the window as in the browser window.

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/resizable/

Comment: Yeah I looked at that, but it's not quite what I'm looking for. I'm not just trying to resize one div but also have another one resize in response to that.

Comment: Like this - http://jqueryui.com/resizable/#synchronous-resize? You can also hook any code you want to the `resize` event. See: http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#event-resize. So you could put custom logic to resize other elements there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out jQuery UI [resizable](http://jqueryui.com/resizable/).

You call it like this:

```
$(function() {
  $( "#resizable" ).resizable();
});
```

which will give an element called `resizable` little resize handles.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [jQuery UI resizable](http://jqueryui.com/resizable/), it does pretty much exactly what you want